# Cakephp can not connect to Sqlserver Express 2008 R2

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008, cakephp

I have this issue:

> CakePHP is NOT able to connect to the database.
>
> Database connection "Sqlserver" is missing, or could not be created.

Details of what I've had so far:

```
public $default = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Sqlserver',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost\SQLEXPRESS',
    'login' => 'login',
    'password' => 'pass',
    'database' => 'prueba',
    'prefix' => '',
    'encoding' => 'utf8'
);
```

and in my xampp\php\php.ini I had this:

```
[PHP_SQLSRV]
extension=php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll //this file exists in xampp\php\ext
[PHP_PDO_SQLSRV]
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll //this file exists in xampp\php\ext
```

I am using:

- XAMPP 3.2.1
- SQL Server 2008 R2
- PHP 5.5.19
- CakePHP 2.6.3.

This works without the framework, but within the **Cakephp** framework it does not work. Why?

Comment: Please check link:- http://samsami2u.wordpress.com/2008/06/30/how-to-connect-mssql-with-php/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to install **Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server** ?

In order to get `pdo_sqlsrv` work you have to install [Microsoft ODBC Driver](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36437)